# Is there a way to undo detached HEAD state without undoing the work I've done while in detached HEAD state?

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I'm in a detached HEAD state but have made a bunch of commits while in detached HEAD that I can't lose. Is there a way to undo the detached HEAD state without losing any of my work?

Answer (score 3):

Just make a branch. That will preserve all the work you've done.

```
# detached head
# work, add, commit; work, add, commit ...
git switch -c saveMe
```

If you want to move your preservation branch commits to a branch that already existed, where you should have been all that time, simply rebase your preservation branch, from the detached head commit to the end, onto the existing branch.

```
git rebase --onto existingBranch <detachPoint> saveMe
```

You can then move the existing branch pointer to the end of the preservation branch, and throw away the preservation branch.

```
git switch existingBranch
git reset --hard saveMe
git branch -D saveMe
```

Thus it will be as if you had done all that work while on the existing branch, as if you had never been in detached head mode at all.